# Installed Guest Additions but nothing changed

Tags: virtualbox

I run VirtualBox 5.1.34_Ubuntu r121010 successfully for a while now with Windows 7 as the guest OS. I wanted to install the guest additions, so I added them through the repos (version: 5.1.34-0ubuntu1.16.04.2).

I enter my guest Windows and install the guest additions and everything works really smoothly but after a successfull install and reboot, simply nothing changed.

I tried this loop now several times and I don't know where to start looking for the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to install guest additions on the guest (windows 7) not the host (ubuntu)

Comment: @Panther I may be misreading the details, but it appears that the OP is saying they "enter my Windows and installed the guest additions" and everything stays the same.  I don't understand the reference to ubuntu's repos.  But I believe he's saying he installed everything he could thought both the host and the guest.

Comment: @user35474 **1)** What differences are you looking for?  What errors are you getting?  **2)** What is it you think you're missing?  I can't tell from the content of your question.

Comment: I installed the guest additions under Windows (my guest OS) of course. What I am missing is being able to access USB-devices, such as a USB stick for example - but I still can't access these. No USB-device shows up in my guest OS, also not in VM itself.

Comment: If I say, not in VM itself, I mean the little icon in the lower status bar.

Comment: Could solve the problem by adding myself to the group "vboxusers".